# Importing Prestashop products with translations

Tags: csv, prestashop

When adding a new product, category, cms page in prestashop, you get the ability to add the translation of the description or product title in the same window by choosing the language from the dropdown to the left of the field.

When I import my products through the CSV Import link in prestashop, I get the ability to choose the language of the *.csv file. OK. This really works… BUT this generates two products to my product list, example (translation in German):

1. My New Ipod
2. Mein neue Ipod

Same goes for categories, it doesn't really combine them into one, you'll get:

1. Art
2. Kunst

I've tried to make the ID field in the *.csv files the same for the main language and the translated language, but this doesn't seem to work.

So my question is for you, prestashop masters, how do I combine a translated product with the original product and to make this by importing csv files?

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer myself then.

1. When importing the csv, maek sure the ID override and Refrence # is turned on
2. Import all the data with your main language in use.
3. Import the translated data, make sure the ID's and Reference # match.
4. Import only the stuff you need. For a translation, you'd only need to import the title, description and translations of features. Everything else will come from the main language.